# Automatically managing bi-directional references in a database in Python

Tags: python, database, bidirectional

I have a ZODB database containing objects that have bi-directional links to each other. These are generally many-to-one and one-to-many links, i.e. groups and members.
Members have a reference to the group to which they belong, and groups have a list of references to their members.

I'm looking for a way to automatically assure that the bi-directional references are consistent. E.g .if the group of `memberA` is changed from `groupA` to `groupB`, then `memberA` should automatically be removed from the list of members of `groupA` and added to the list of `groupB`.

The code below is one way to do it.

```py
class Group:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.members = []
        self.db_ref = None

    def add_member(self, member, cascade=True):
        self.members.append(member)
        if cascade:
            self.db_ref.member_of_group_changed(self, member)

    def remove_member(self, member, cascade=True):
        self.members.remove(member)
        if cascade:
            self.db_ref.member_of_group_changed(self, member)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '("' + self.name + '")'


class Member:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.group = None
        self.db_ref = None

    def set_group(self, group, cascade=True):
        old_group = self.group
        self.group = group
        if cascade:
            self.db_ref.group_of_member_changed(self, old_group)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '("' + self.name + '")'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.groups = []
        self.members = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        item.db_ref = self
        if type(item) is Group:
            self.groups.append(item)
        elif type(item) is Member:
            self.members.append(item)

    def group_of_member_changed(self, member, old_group):
        if not old_group is None:  # group unset
            old_group.remove_member(member, cascade=False)
        elif not member.group is None:  # group set
            member.group.add_member(member, cascade=False)

    def member_of_group_changed(self, group, member):
        if member in group.members:  # member added to group
            member.set_group(group, cascade=False)
        else:  # member removed from group
            member.set_group(None, cascade=False)


db = Database()
groupA = Group("groupA")
memberA = Member("memberA")
memberB = Member("memberB")
db.add_item(groupA)
db.add_item(memberA)
db.add_item(memberB)

# add memberA to groupA
groupA.add_member(memberA)
print(groupA.members)  # [Member("memberA")]
print(memberA.group)  # Group("groupA")

# set group of memberB to groupA
memberB.set_group(groupA)
print(memberB.group)  # Group("groupA")
print(groupA.members)  # [Member("memberA"), Member("memberB")]

# remove memberB from groupA
groupA.remove_member(memberB)
print(groupA.members)  # [Member("memberA")]
print(memberB.group)  # None

# unset group of memberA
memberA.set_group(None)
print(memberA.group)  # None
print(groupA.members)  # []
```

However, it feels kind of clumsy. I suspect that there are better ways since I imagine this situation occurs frequently. It would be great if one didn't need to define methods like `set_group()` or `add_member()` but could modify the setter and append functions, i.e.:

```py
groupA.members.append(memberA) # also sets sets memberA.group to groupA
memberB.group = groupA # also adds memberB to groupA.members
```

As in the provided code sample, I prefer that that updating references is handled via the `Database` class. E.g. for `memberB.group = groupA`, the setter method setting `memberB.group` to `groupA`, should not directly call the `append` method for adding `memberB` to `groupA`. The database should do this.

I looked into descriptors. I guess the function `__set__()` could be a replacement for `set_group()`, but this is not an option for `add_member()`/`remove_member()`.

What would be *really* cool is if this behavior could be added dynamically when an object is added to the database. But perhaps I'm getting greedy :).

Comment: Probably better suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: OK thanks. If I don't get a response here I'll try CR